# how to parse fb image url in to image in to $_GET

Tags: javascript, php

How can I parse a fb image url in to image into `$_GET`? I am using javascript and php:

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/c0.8.50.50/p50x50/10418963_845746262178119_4978000552642842671_n.jpg?oh=21e838bf609a8f4b0137a786c7434ee3&oe=58144D56&__gda__=1479268869_857fd43604c037bdf53d104a318910c6

$image= $_GET[picture];
```

Comment: no idea what your asking

Comment: i get a image url from facebook how to save into phpmysql as image @Dagon

Comment: very basically: `$Img = file_get_contents($source);    file_put_contents($target, $Img);`

Comment: The answer would be, "It depends."

Comment: @dagon can u explain the code how to file_put..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$source="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/c0.8.50.50/p50x50/10418963_845746262178119_4978000552642842671_n.jpg?oh=21e838bf609a8f4b0137a786c7434ee3&oe=58144D56&__gda__=1479268869_857fd43604c037bdf53d104a318910c6";

$target="server_file_path/image.jpg";//location and name on local server, may not be a jpg, you need to check the file type.

$Img = file_get_contents($source); //get the image from the remote server

file_put_contents($target, $Img); //save the image locally
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
file_get_contents($file)
```

that accepts URI's to